# Display uploaded/chosen image without saving it in database in Django

Tags: python, django

I'd like to store the image which the user uploads, in a variable within views.py (and apply some opencv operations on it) and then display the resultant image. **I don't want to store the image in a database**. So, i don't think models are necessary for implementing this. How to proceed further? Following are the `index.html` and `views.py`. Sorry if any coding mistakes are there, i'm new to Django.

**index.html**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="file-field input-field left">
        <div class="btn black-text waves-effect waves-dark" style="background-color: #F5DF73">
            <div>Upload</div>
            <input type="file" name = "input_image" onchange="readURL(this);">
        </div>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
           {#<input class="file-path validate" type="text">#}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ image }}
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def upload_pic(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        image = form.cleaned_data['image']

    return render(request, 'html/index.html', {"image": image})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
]
```

Comment: Well, you seem to have done it. What is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman how should i display the image in index.html? Whatever i've done until now doesn't display the image

Comment: Image needs to be stored in your file system to be able to be served as static file.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Can't i just simply display `image` variable which is present in `views.py` ?

Comment: No. because images served as static files. They downloaded separately from your html by your browser.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev not only sending it as static files.It can convert to base64 strings and can render it through context variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it by doing this:

**views.py**

```
def process_image(request):

    # inputImage is the name attribute of the <input> tag in the html
    inImg = request.FILES["inputImage"].read()

    encoded = b64encode(inImg)
    mime = "image/jpg"
    mime = mime + ";" if mime else ";"
    input_image = "data:%sbase64,%s" % (mime, encoded)        

    return render(request, "../templates/index.html", {{ "input_image": input }})
```

**index.html:**

```
<input src = '{{ input_image }}' name = 'inputImage' type="text">
```

Comment: If it helps anyone, to get it working, I changed this line: ``encoded = b64encode(inImg)`` to this ``encoded = b64encode(inImg).decode('ascii')``

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST)
image = form.cleaned_data['image']
b64_img = base64.b64encode(image.file.read())

return render(request, 'html/index.html', {"image": b64_img})
```

In html

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}">
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what should be in the action attr of the form ?

Comment: action attribute is "url" to which you have to post image

Comment: This just shows a really long string in my rendered template instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works

```
import io
import base64
data = io.BytesIO()
image.save(data, "JPEG")
encoded_img_data = base64.b64encode(data.getvalue())
out=encoded_img_data.decode('utf-8')
```

views.py function

```
return render(request, 'html/index.html', {"image": out})
```

index.html

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}">
```