# Pass Image data of one view obtained from POST method to other view without using any Databases

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, nonetype

I am working on a Django project . It fundamentally contains two views.

First is HomePageView. It contains a form that take image input from user(anonymous).On submitting the form, user gets redirected to the second view, ResultView.

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField(label = 'Choose an image below.')
```

#### views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *
import base64




def HomePageView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST , request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image_object = request.FILES['image']

             #or should i use : image_object = form.cleaned_data['image']
             #or should i use : image_object = request.POST.get('image')

            request.session['image_object'] = image_object
            return redirect(to='ResultView')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()

    params = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'home.html', params)
```

#### home.html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token%}
  
       <!--- Styling --->

      <div class="col-md-8  mt-4 pt-5">

        <div class="container mt-5 ">
          <div class="row p-3 ">
            <div class="col-md-12  align-items-center">
              {{ form.as_p }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 ms-3"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark font-monospace" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">SUMBIT</button></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</form>
```

Now, I want to obtain the image that user has uploaded. Pass it to the result view, do some ML processing, and then display it on template of ResultView, without using any database. However, for now, I have just written the code that just do enough processing so that it can be displayed on the webpage without needing databse.

#### views.py

I referenced this thread for this part: [Display uploaded/chosen image without saving it in database in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503111/display-uploaded-chosen-image-without-saving-it-in-database-in-django)

```
def ResultView(request):
    image_object = request.session.get('image_object')
    b64_img = base64.b64encode(image_object.file.read())
    context = {'img':b64_img}
    return render(request, 'result.html',context)
```

#### result.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} RESULT {% endblock %}

<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{img}}">

{% block body %} 
{% endblock %}
```

Now, when i run the app and input an image, it gives following error:

**

```
Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable
```

**.

How can I resolve these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Code snippet

```
def HomePageView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST , request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image_object = request.FILES['image']
            #or should i use : image_object = form.cleaned_data['image']
            #or should i use : image_object = request.POST.get('image')
            request.session['image_object'] = str(request.build_absolute_uri(image_object))
            return redirect(to='ResultView')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()

    params = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'home.html', params)


def ResultView(request):
    image_object = request.session.get('image_object')
    context = {'img':image_object}
    return render(request, 'result.html',context)
```